# Where to download the debian historical versions such as debian-7.8 or debian6?

Tags: debian

In almost every Debian image mirror site , historical Debian version are not put on the mirror site. Only the current version is put on the mirror site.
Where can I download the Debian historical versions such as Debian-7.8 or Debian6?

Answer (score 2):

The list of all the [mirrors](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list)

Click [here](http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/dists/)

Comment: none of them list the hitorical version such as debian6 iso file.

Comment: [Archives](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/)